# calling codeigniter method from javascript and passing data

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, parameter-passing

Hello I am using codeigniter framework for my college project ,and I need to call controllers method from js function, and i manage to do that, but now I dont know how to pass data to that method that I am calling. I was found some examples on web but I didn't manage to solve my problem.

This is how I call my method from js function,

```
window.location.href = "<?php echo site_url('controller_user/test');?>";
```

and I need to send this data to that method

```
var data = [formName, formSurname, formEmail, formUsername];
```

And I try something like this:

```
window.location.href = "<?php echo site_url('controller_user/test');?>?data="+data;
```

I don't know what to do to solve this problem, like I said I found something similar on stackoverflow site but still having trouble.

Thanks to everyone willing to help me!!!

Comment: either make a HTML form with data in hidden fields & then submit it using JavaScript or use AJAX here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please modify your JavaScript like the following

```
window.location.href = "<?php echo site_url('controller_user/test');?>/"+formName+/+formSurname+'/'+formEmail+'/'+formUsername;
```

modify your controller function like the following

```
public function test($formName='',$formSurname='',$formEmail='',formUsername=''){

    echo "$formName ,$formSurname,$formEmail,formUsername";
    exit;

}
```

Comment: I probably made a mistake somewhere, because it doesn't do anything, I will try again and I will tell you did I succeed. Thank you for the answer!!!

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I made a mistake and fix it, and now your code works fine!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
window.location.href = "<?php echo json_encode(site_url('controller_user/test'));?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use ajax and passed the data to method . like this , try out

```
var data = {formName : formName , formSurname : formSurname ,formEmail : formEmail,formUsername : formUsername}

     $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo base_url('controller_user/test');?>',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            success: function(msg)
            {
                //success part code 
            }
        });
        return false;
```

Comment: I probably made a mistake somewhere, because it doesn't do anything, I will try again and I will tell you did I succeed. Thank you for the answer!!!